# getting one column Count based on joining 3 tables in Sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I ahve one task to do.

```
i have 3 tables like

**Table1**

QuesionsetID        
AssessmentID

**Table 2**

QuestionSetID          
 QuestionID 

**Table 3**

QuestionID                  
 Question           
 DifficultyLevel

Now I want

 **Count(Question)** Where **QuestionSetID=QuestionSetID** and **QuestionID=QuestionID** and **DifficultyLevel='LOW'**

note:
**QuestionSetID** will have one Item..i.e say for ex:EmcetQustionSet....
**QuestionID**-->EmcetQuestionSet contains for example 100 questions....
**difficultyLevel**--->Each Question have Difficult levels i.e Low, High, medium


result O/p should be

**CountOfDifficultyLOWLevel**

10

20

4

6

Important Note: **Table 1 is the MAIN table for Joining
Based on Table 1 we have to do Join Table2 and table 3**.

**
```

> solution be like this

**: Using Tbale 1 **QuestionSetID**, we have to get     **Count(Question)** where **difficultylevel='Low'** using Table 2 and Table 3
    Alliances names for Tbales is:

```
Table1:A(main Table)

Table 2:B

tbale 3:C 

  How can I writemy query in order to get what I want?   
hope u understand this..This is urjent..Plz 

Thanks in Advance
```

The only problematic this is that you need to discard the case where st1 and st2 are matching the same row.In the SQL above I have assumed that the sourceTable has a PK I've called RowID and exclude the case where its joining a row to itself. I've also changed the HAVING line as that didn't seem to be what your description of the problem called for: it sounded like it was better in the WHERE clause. The new HAVING clause is actually redundant: it should never have a count(*) of 0, but it won't hurt.

Comment: can you what you do and what error you get , you cant just ask what you want , show some your efforts

Comment: A better way to arrange your database would be to have a single table with questions; QuestionID | SetID | AssessmentID | Difficulty | Value.

Comment: hi.IS it possible to get Only Count(Questions) where difficultlevel="LOw" using QuestionsetID from Table 1

Comment: Do you mean, you want Question count for each QuestionSetID where difficultylevel is Low?

Comment: You request is kind of blurry to say the least. "Using Tbale 1 \*\*QuestionSetID, we have to get Count(Question) where difficultylevel='Low' using Table 2 and Table 3" is a very technical "task". It sounds like you want to count low level questions. That would be a simple select from the questions table, which you call "table3" for some strange reason. But one *must* use table1??? Why? It seems to have nothing to do with the required result. And what does the QuestionSetID have to do with it? And how do you get *four* result values? The number of low level questions is just *one* number.

Comment: Hi  Thorsten Kettner,
here QuestionSetID means for example I have QuestionSet item named as
"Emcet" 
In Emcet QuestionSet i have 30 Questions. Each question having it's difficulty Level like Low, High, medium. so i have to get the result values as shown in above

Comment: That is still blurry. Do you want one record per QuestionSetID? This is what Nithin Gangadharan already asked. You didn't answer. And you would get for example the result list 10/20/4/6 or 4/20/6/10 and the order wouldn't matter? Yes? And again: why must you select from table1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS per my understanding I think the following query should work:

```
SELECT Table2.QuestionSetID,
       COUNT(QuestionID)
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN Table3
ON Table2.QuesionID = Table3.QuesionID
WHERE difficultylevel='Low'
GROUP BY Table2.QuestionSetID
```

Comment: hi Nithin
Yes u did is right. I did it too.But it results 2 columns. i.e QuestionsetID and Count(QuestionID)...Can we make it one column.i.e Count(QuestionID)..i mean is it possible for without GroupBy clause??

Comment: You want it for single QuestionSetID?
eg:Select ...
   ...
   Where QuestionSetID = 10;

Comment: the above query results the correct o/p but here i don't want to show the column "QuestionSetID" in table

Comment: You can just remove the QuestionSetID from SELECT clasue. It will give  you the output you looking for.

Comment: @sureshchowdary05: As Nithin sais: simply remove the column from your select list. You should have known this yourself. Is this your first select query? I'd like to add that it is strange to show the counts without their QuestionSetID. You'd get a list of values without knowing what they refer to.

Comment: Thank u Nithin..i did it in another way...but ur answer helps me a lot..Thank u

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: Thank u for giving valuable suggestion to me.I think i have to improve a lot #respect